Movie about a girl who falls in love with the son of her mother's lover
This movie is in English, however seems to be British or Australian. It's probably from the 60's to the 80's. Saw it on one of TV station with old movies. 
A girl travels overseas after she finds a letter that her mother left when she had died. 
The girl decides to find the man that her mother had been in love with during the war. When she finds him, the man lives in a mansion with a tall brick fence. She's caught climbing the fence to get to his home and his son catches her. They end up falling in love. 
Later on in the movie she finds out this man/father is actually her biological father which she didn't know about. His son, now the lover of the girl, finds out later that he is not the natural son by blood to the man/father, so they can marry.

Hi. Do you remember the approximate year of release? Where did you see it?

Probably 60's to the 80's. Saw it on one of TV station with old movies.

This sounds like Tears in the Rain from 1988 with Sharon Stone.

When Casey Cantrell's mother died, her last wish was that her daughter would give a letter to Lord Richard Bredon, living in the UK. When Casey arrives in London, Lord Bredon denies ever having known her mother. Casey meets Lord Bredon's son Michael and both fall in love. When Lord Bredon realizes this new relationship he gets really angry, assuming Casey wants to blackmail his family somehow, and begins to investigate her background. The plot heightens dramatically when it appears that an event from the past might part the lovers.

In the end, they can be together because they're not really blood related: It turns out Michael is Richard's and Casey's mother's son, but Casey's adopted, so all is well (yeah, it's a bit of a mess). Here are the first few minutes, where Casey tries to climb the wall surrounding the Lord's mansion and the son catches her:



